# Login functionality in Joomla Component

Tags: joomla

How can I integrate Login functionality in a custom component with Joomla database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code

```
$result = JFactory::getApplication()->login(array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
```

You need to create a form with fields username and password. And need to a URL in  in form action.